# Can I dismiss the local notification when next time the app launch?

Tags: ios, serialization, uilocalnotification, notificationcenter

I know I can cancel the notification when user tap this notification in notification center . But can I cancel the notification in other palce where I can't get the related local notification from system. Can I serialize the local notification, and cancel it when the app runs next time?

Sorry for make you misunderstand!

**I want to dismiss a posted notification in the notification center, but not a scheduled one.
So what I want to ask is how to save the local notification object, then I can use it dismiss itself when next time the app launch. Maybe this job can't be done with current sdk.**

Answer (score 2):

If you need to cancel all notification you can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

For cancelling a particular notification:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:aNotification];
```

For getting the particular Notification you can use:

```
NSArray *notifArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (int i = 0; i < [notifArray count]; i++)
{
    UILocalNotification *aEvent = [notifArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *userInfo = aEvent.userInfo;
    NSString *notifId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfo valueForKey:@"id"]];
    if ([id isEqualToString:cancelId])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:aEvent];
        break;
    }
}
```

Here:

- You need to store a id key value pair in the `userInfo` of your notification for identifying particular local notification
- `cancelId` is the id of notification which you want to cancel (Stored in user info)

Comment: I think this is not I want. I want to dismiss a posted notification in the notification center, but not a scheduled one

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question deals with cancelling already delivered notifications, not scheduled ones.

Comment: @steveluscher: You are correct, but he edited his question after I answered, Please check the edited date. The bold part was not there in his original question.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code to get all scheduled notifications:

```
NSArray *reminderArray=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

Then you can select the notification required and delete it.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelLocalNotification:yourNotification];
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question deals with cancelling already delivered notifications, not scheduled ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you save a link to your notification, then you will can cancel it before it fires.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelLocalNotification:yourNotification];
```

Comment: Indeed you can, but if your app resigns before you get a chance to make use of it, the reference to the `UILocalNotification` will go with it.

Comment: You can save reference to UILocalNotification  to User Defaults or to another place